# Angular Factory Not passing data back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am trying to create an Angular Factory, this is based on a example from a plural site course http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=shawn-wildermuth&name=site-building-m7&mode=live&clip=3&course=site-building-bootstrap-angularjs-ef-azure.

From debugging the code in Chrome it appears to run fine.  I can see when I debug it that the service gets my data and puts it in my array but when I look at the controller in either $scope.data or dataService.data the arrays are empty. I don't see any javascript errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions. I'm using AngularJS v1.3.15.

```
module.factory("dataService", function($http,$routeParams,$q) {
var _data = [];

var _getData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("/api/v1/myAPI?mainType=" + $routeParams.mainType + "&subType=" + $routeParams.subType)
        .then(function (result) {
            angular.copy(result.data,_data);
            deferred.resolve();
        },
        function () {
            //Error
            deferred.reject();
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};

return {
    data: _data,
    getData: _getData
};});

module.controller('dataController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'dataService',function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, dataService) {
$scope.data = dataService;
$scope.dataReturned = true;
$scope.isBusy = true;

dataService.getData().then(function () {
    if (dataService.data == 0)
        $scope.dataReturned = false;
},
function () {
    //Error
    alert("could not load data");
})
.then(function () {
    $scope.isBusy = false;
})}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

On

```
return {
  data: _data,
  getData: _getData
};});
```

you have "data: _data," while your array is named just "data". Change the name of the variable to match and it will work:

```
var _data = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there are some errors in your codes :

- In your Service, you define `var data = [];`, but you return `data: _data,`. So you should correct the defination to `var _data = []`
- you don't define `_bling`, but you use `angular.copy(result.data,_bling);`

One more question, why do you assigne the service to `$scope.data` : `$scope.data = dataService` ?

EDIT :
Notice that there 3 changes in the following codes:

1. comment the `$scope.data = dataService;`, because it makes no sense, and I think that `$scope.data` should be the data that the service returns.
2. `$scope.data = dataService.data;`, as I described in 1st point. You can see the result from the console.
3. In the if condition, I think that you want to compare the length of the returned data array, but not the data.

   ```
   module.controller('dataController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'dataService',function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, dataService) {
   // $scope.data = dataService;
   $scope.dataReturned = true;
   $scope.isBusy = true;

   dataService.getData().then(function () {
       if (dataService.data.length === 0){
           $scope.dataReturned = false;
       }else{
           $scope.data = dataService.data;
           console.log($scope.data);
       }
   },
   // other codes...
   })}]);
   ```

Comment: Sorry about that those errors were created when i put the code here.  Not sure how that happened its my first time asking on stack overflow.  I have fixed the post above but still have the same issue.

As to why am I doing it this way.  Well that is how the example I was following did it.  Seemed odd to me to.  He said something about it being able to detect changes to the data service.  The whole idea is that I can store a shared copy of the data here and reduce round trips to the server.  Not sure I really like it to be honest and I had all this working find without the service.

Comment: @AndrewCrowder I have modified my answer to give you some codes. It should work. Can u try it?

Comment: Thanks I did get it work work using code similar to yours but it seemed intermittent it would work for a while then just stop when I made some very small tweak to the java script.

Since I had a non-factory version working before I am just going to go back to that.  I know credit for answers is a big thing here and not sure what do since I'm the one giving up on the solution not you.   I really do appreciate your time and the help you have provided.

Comment: @AndrewCrowder For the votes, just take it easy. If I can help you, I would be pleasured.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use deferred from $q this way?

The proper way to use $q:

```
$http.get("/api/v1/myAPI?mainType=" + $routeParams.mainType + "&subType=" + $routeParams.subType)
    .success(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }).error(
    function () {
        //Error
        deferred.reject();
    });
```

And then in controller

```
dataService
    .getData()
    .then(function success(result) {
        $scope.data = result; //assing retrived data to scope variable
    },
    function error() {
        //Error
        alert("could not load data");
    });
```

Comment: So when I try it this way I get an error of on the .then statement

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at new <anonymous>

Comment: @AndrewCrowder Do you still have "return deferred.promise;" line in _getData function? It's still obligatory to return promise from there.

Comment: Thanks I think I took that out not thinking it was needed anymore.  However I think I am going to drop this whole approach as there is something I obviously don't understand about it.   I got it to work but then I make one little tweak to what appears to unrelated JavaScript and it stops working. 

Since I had a non-factory version working before I am just going to go back to that.  

I know credit for answers is a big thing here and not sure what do since I'm the one giving up on the solution not you. I really do appreciate your time and the help you have provided.